# Filter unique values in column conditional on category in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to filter out unique values in df1 col1 that are existing for all unique values in df1 col2.
What would be a good way to approach this problem?

Example to illustrate the problem.

```
d = {
     'col1': ['alfa','alfa','beta','beta','beta','charlie','delta','delta','echo','foxtrot','foxtrot'], 
     'col2': ['sweden','norway','norway','sweden','denmark','norway','sweden','norway','denmark','denmark','norway']
    }

     df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

     print(df)


col1    col2
alfa    sweden
alfa    norway
beta    norway
beta    sweden
beta    denmark
charlie norway
delta   sweden
delta   norway
echo    denmark
foxtrot denmark
foxtrot norway
```

Wanted result:
df2

```
col1   col2 
beta   [norway, sweden, denmark]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `set` of unique country names, group col2 values into a list by col1, and then apply a boolean mask by comparing the sets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
unique = set(df["col2"].unique())
grouped = df.groupby("col1")["col2"].apply(list)
x = df.groupby("col1")["col2"].apply(set)==unique

print (grouped[x])

#
col1
beta    [norway, sweden, denmark]
```

Comment: Many thanks for supporting with a solution, it solves the problem I'm dealing with.

For a clarification on the group, split, apply method:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-the-split-apply-combine-strategy-in-pandas-groupby-29e0eb44b62e